# Java Load folder from jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, spring-boot

I'm trying to load files from folder, but java code cannot load folder if it run inside jar

In dev, code works fine, in server (java -jar myapp) it not works (spring boot application)

```
        Path path = Paths.get("/home/toto/reports")

        File dir = new File(path.toAbsolutePath().toUri());
        log.info(path + " is directory : " + dir.isDirectory());
```

True in dev mode, false on server

Help

EDIT : 
I want to load all xlsx files from a folder "reports"
At first, this folder was inside the project under "resources" folder

```
 URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("reports");
 Path path = Paths.get(resource.toURI());
 Files.walk(path)
                .forEach(filePath -> {
                   // excel file
                   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(Files.newInputStream(excelFilePath));
                   ...
                });
```

Works fine on development (intelliJ), but not on server (jar)

So I move folder outside the jar 
Previous code works in development, but not on server

Comment: Is the path to the file the exact same on the server?

Comment: What is it, what you actually want to do? What do you want to do with this folder? If you want to access resources from it, you can do that, no matter if from file system or .jar file. If you want to list it's resources, it becomes a little bit more trickier, but doable, with Spring.

Comment: I finally put all excel files name into a file (in dev mode), and read line by line this file for open excel file (in server mode)